# Passing a query result to be executted

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, indexing

I want to pass the results of the following query into its own query:

```
SELECT
  'CREATE INDEX [missing_index_' 
  + CONVERT (VARCHAR, mig.index_group_handle) + '_' 
  + CONVERT (VARCHAR, mid.index_handle) + '_' 
  + LEFT (PARSENAME (mid.statement, 1),32) + ']' 
  + ' ON ' + mid.statement + ' (' + ISNULL(mid.equality_columns, '') 
  + 
  CASE
    WHEN mid.equality_columns IS NOT NULL AND mid.inequality_columns IS NOT NULL 
    THEN ','
    ELSE ''
  END
  + ISNULL(mid.inequality_columns, '') + ')' 
  + ISNULL(' INCLUDE (' + mid.included_columns + ')', '') AS create_index_statement
FROM sys.dm_db_missing_index_groups mig
INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats migs ON migs.group_handle = mig.index_group_handle
INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_details mid ON mig.index_handle = mid.index_handle
WHERE
  migs.avg_total_user_cost * (migs.avg_user_impact / 100.0) 
    * (migs.user_seeks + migs.user_scans) > 10
```

Comment: You will have to use a stored procedure or some outside scripting program to take the results of the one query and generate a new sql statement that is then submitted back to the database to be executed. A good place to start is the [MSDN article on Dynamic SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) using sp_executesql in a proc.

Comment: Often times the suggested indexes here are just plain evil. They can sometimes help but other times those recommendations will make everything far slower. I would use those as new indexes in any system extremely carefully and would caution you against automating adding indexes to your system like this.

Answer (score 1):

You could concatenate all your rows into a single string, the execute that using sp_executesql

```
-- BUILD STATEMENT
DECLARE
    @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX) = (
        SELECT
            'CREATE INDEX [missing_index_' + CONVERT (
                VARCHAR(MAX)(,
                mig.index_group_handle
            ) + '_' + CONVERT (VARCHAR, mid.index_handle) + '_' + LEFT (
                PARSENAME (mid.statement, 1),
                32
            ) + ']' + ' ON ' + mid.statement + ' (' + ISNULL(mid.equality_columns, '') + CASE
        WHEN mid.equality_columns IS NOT NULL
        AND mid.inequality_columns IS NOT NULL THEN
            ','
        ELSE
            ''
        END + ISNULL(mid.inequality_columns, '') + ')' + ISNULL(
            ' INCLUDE (' + mid.included_columns + ')',
            ''
        ) + ';' AS create_index_statement
        FROM
            sys.dm_db_missing_index_groups mig
        INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats migs ON migs.group_handle = mig.index_group_handle
        INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_missing_index_details mid ON mig.index_handle = mid.index_handle
        WHERE
            migs.avg_total_user_cost * (migs.avg_user_impact / 100.0) * (
                migs.user_seeks + migs.user_scans
            ) > 10 FOR XML PATH (''),
            TYPE ).
        VALUE
            ('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)');

-- EXECUTE STATEMENT
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL;
```

**HOWEVER** I would strongly advise against creating indexes is this manner, it does there are too many other factors to consider when creating indexes, this does not consider a read/write ratio, or lots of similar suggestions that could be amalgamated into one etc. Indexing is as much of an art than it is a science, so I don't think there is a magic fix query that can do this for you.

Comment: You should also [always supply a length when converting to, or declaring `NVARCHAR/NCHAR/CHAR/VARCHAR`](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)